# spring xd 1.1.0.M2 fails to start

Tags: spring-xd

I just downloaded spring-xd-1.1.0.M2.zip and followed instructions on below link to install it :
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-xd/1.1.0.M2/reference/html/

I have Java7 on my machine (thats the only prerequisite listed).

When i try to start spring xd, it fails with below exception :
C:\Softwares\spring-xd-1.1.0.M2\xd\bin>xd-singlenode

```
Started : SingleNodeApplication
Documentation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki

14:55:20,358 1.1.0.M2 ERROR main boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.kohsuke.args4j.IllegalAnnotationError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.createOptionHandler(CmdLineParser.java:176)
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.addOption(CmdLineParser.java:131)
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:34)
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.<init>(CmdLineParser.java:91)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.onApplicationEvent(CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.java:69
)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.onApplicationEvent(CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.java:45
)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:286)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerBootstrapContext.<init>(ContainerBootstrapContext.java:48)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.SingleNodeApplication.run(SingleNodeApplication.java:53)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.SingleNodeApplication.main(SingleNodeApplication.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.createOptionHandler(CmdLineParser.java:170)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal hexadecimal escape sequence near index 36
.*C:\Softwares\spring-xd-1.1.0.M2\xd\lib\messagebus\([^/]*).*
                                    ^
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.x(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.escape(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.init(ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.java:91)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.<init>(ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.java:58)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandlers$SingleNodeDataTransportOptionHandler.<init>(ResourcePatternScanningOptionHan
dlers.java:51)
        ... 19 more
Exception in thread "main" org.kohsuke.args4j.IllegalAnnotationError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.createOptionHandler(CmdLineParser.java:176)
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.addOption(CmdLineParser.java:131)
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:34)
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.<init>(CmdLineParser.java:91)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.onApplicationEvent(CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.java:69
)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.onApplicationEvent(CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.java:45
)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:286)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerBootstrapContext.<init>(ContainerBootstrapContext.java:48)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.SingleNodeApplication.run(SingleNodeApplication.java:53)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.SingleNodeApplication.main(SingleNodeApplication.java:46)
```

I downloaded spring-xd-1.0.3.RELEASE.zip and it works fine.
Anyone aware of this issue with the latest version of spring-xd ?

Thanks
Ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved on master: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/commit/386762afd49f5b1173190dcbfda4c17bafda412f

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a problem with the back-whack used by windows as a directory separator.

Something must have changed between 1.0.x and 1.1.x with the way this is handled.

I created a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2539).